# cin inside a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I have written a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a, b;
  while (cin >> a >> b)     //Note the cin inside while loop
  { 
    cout << a << b << "\n";
  }
}
```

We know that `while` loop functions only when the expression evaluates `true` (`1`) or `false`(`0`).
How come `cin` is evaluating `true` and `false`.

Also **how is while loop running when I am entering a number and stops when I enter something non-digit**? How is it evaluating true and false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you writes `cin >> a`, you are actually using the `std::istream::operator>>`, according to the reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), this operator **returns an `istream&` object reference**, and took the right hand variable (reference) as its argument. This is how you can chain it like: `cin >> a >> b`.

To see this `cin >> a >> b` chain another way, when break down, it is this two steps:

- First step, `cin >> a` returns some intermediate value, let's say it is `x`. (You can actually try `auto x = cin >> a`.
- Second step, you are doing `(cin >> a) >> b`, when we use this intermediate value `x`, we could write it as `x >> b`.

So what the hell is this `x`? `x` here stays a same position as the `cin`, it is an object of `istream&` type.

Therefore, when you talk about `true` or `false`, you are actually talking about whether this returned `istream&` reference, refer to an object, whether it is `true` or `false`. It would be `false` when the standard output catch an EOF sign (like when you type Ctrl-C in unix like system, or when you have read to the end of a file).

Your code, therefore, could be expanded as

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a, b;
  auto x = cin >> a >> b
  while (x)
  { 
    cout << a << b << "\n";
  }
}
```

If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio, you could point your mouse at the variable `x`, it would prompt you `x`'s type, and that would be an `istream&`.

Also, thanks to Bob__, this `istream&` class could be convert to an `ios::operator bool` class, as is written [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), whether it is `true` or `false` represents the state(`ios_base::iostate`) of this `stream`, it therfore,

> makes it possible to use streams and functions that return references to streams as loop conditions, resulting in the idiomatic C++ input loops such as `while(stream >> value) {...}` or `while(getline(stream, string)){...}`. Such loops execute the loop's body only if the input operation succeeded.

To further your understanding, you should read the operator (overloading) chapter in your textbook.

Comment: You should probably mention [operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) too.

Comment: @Chazeon: The updated answer is really explanatory. Thanks. :)